# CAGradientLayer not fit perfectly on UITableViewCell bounds

Tags: swift, uitableview, cashapelayer, cagradientlayer

i am developing simple UITableView with custom UITableViewCell with Xib file
i have added MainView and pin it to ContentView in order to add all my views inside MainView
as shown below
[UITableViewCell layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIYQK.png)

when i try to add CAGradientLayer to MainView it doesnt fit perfectly on mainView bounds as i show below
[whats happening on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHfbg.png)
i use this piece of code to add CAGradientLayer

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
      let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
      mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
      gradient.frame = mainView.frame
      gradient.colors = [ColorCompatibility.gradEnd.cgColor, ColorCompatibility.gradStart.cgColor]
      gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
      gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
     // gradient.cornerRadius = 20
      
      gradient.shadowColor = ColorCompatibility.systemBackground.cgColor
      gradient.shadowOpacity = 0.8
      gradient.shadowOffset = .zero
      gradient.shadowRadius = 5
      gradient.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mainView.layer.bounds, cornerRadius: 20).cgPath
      gradient.shouldRasterize = true
      gradient.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
   
      contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
   
    
}
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: what is mainView ?

Comment: Shouldn't be `contentView` instead of `mainView` ?

Comment: mainView is a secondry View i added to contentView in order to now using contentView directly .

Comment: whats frame of mainView ?

Comment: contentview by 10points inset on every side

Comment: give it contentView frame ... it will fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here. The first is that in `awakeFromNib` the cell (and its content view) most likely doesn't have the correct frame so you *could* use another life cycle hook where the frame is correct but then you would run into problems when the device is rotated so the cell frame changes at runtime.

I would suggest to update the gradient layers frame in `layoutSublayers(of:)`. Let's assume you created a property for the layer called `gradient`:

```
override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)

    gradient.frame = mainView.bounds
}
```

Comment: this actualy works but it hase a very little problem is that it fix the frame only when i start scrollling

Comment: thank you so much i fix that one with LayoutIfNeeded() on viewdidapear